# apt-get update command not running correctly

Tags: apt

While running apt install curl command this error has been displayed and apt-get update also
not updating every packages i am not aware of this error

```
ubuntu@master:~$ sudo apt install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'curl' has no installation candidate



ubuntu@master:~$ sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Packages are built for specific releases, and you've not told us your release thus we're somewhat limited as we only know what you tell us. First step is to `sudo apt update` and check all lines are present, none missing, and no warnings or error messages.